# How can I have subcommands with a "fallthrough" behavior?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program which is basically a kind of web client, so mostly the user will be running it with a single parameter, a URL:

```
myclient https://example.com
```

But occasionally the user might want to configure the program using a subcommand:

```
myclient configure-this ...
myclient configure-that ...
myclient configure-other ...
```

So I'd like to use subparsers to handle the subcommands, but I want a kind of "fallthrough" where if the first argument isn't recognized as any subcommand, the script just assumes it's a URL.

Can this be done using `argparse`?

Comment: I don't think you can do this; once you add subparsers the command name becomes a required argument. Strictly on the opinion side of things, I think the semantics you've proposed here lead to a confusing user interface, because you can't differentiate between "unknown subcommand" and "mistyped url".

Comment: I think the closest you can get is to define the URL as a flagged (optionals) argument.  `subparser` is a positional argument, identified strictly by position, not value.  By default `subparser` is not required, so the user can omit it. but he can't substitute another string.